# How to update URL on page scroll without hooks in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, smooth-scrolling, react-class-based-component

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling page in React. The page is split into 4 sections:

Overview

About us

Courses

News

So on scrolling, if it's at the section 'News' with the id=news the URL should be updated to: website.com/specific-string#news so he can copy this link, and when you access this URL to send you directly to that section.

I am using react version 16.3.1. So cannot use hooks here.

After adding this smooth scroll feature, I need to display a button which will download the content in the section in the viewport.
I am new to react and trying to learn new things by challenging myself everyday. Anyone who could guide me here?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use hooks?

Comment: I want to explore the possibilities with class based components.

Comment: Then you could achieve that with just javascript, you can check if an element is inside the viewport and manipulate whatever when it happens. I remember doing something similar with the help from this [post](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = element.id  // here is the element id
```

Or like this if you do not want to scroll to the element

```
history.pushState({}, "", element.id)
```

You can update your location hash like this.

If you don't know how to get the element id, you can use IntersectionObserver

It all can be done without hooks